# Keycloak extend EventType

Tags: java, keycloak

I have Keycloak extension for MFA using codes sent by emails. On successful MFA I would like to send custom "MFA" event.

I know that Keycloak sends and stores events on various actions like Login, Login_error, Logout etc. I found api to create and send events, but this requires EventType enum as parameter that i am not sure how to extend or if this is even possible.

```
EventBuilder event = context.getEvent();
event.event("MFA"); // This need to be EventType enum, therefore "MFA" does not work/compile
event.success();
context.success();
```

Broader context is that I am developing conditional authenticator that is supposed to trigger MFA authenticator based on date of last successful MFA. After successful MFA I would like to send an event, and then in conditional authenticator I would like to look for last success MFA event for given user.

The only examples i found on the web are how to implement custom event listeners for already existing events within Keycloak.

Comment: did you extend the EventType?

Comment: Hi, no. In the end I stored successful MFA date in User Attributes. I don't think extending EventType is possible atm.